# C# WEB server download HELP C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to build an application that can update my companies products. I am trying to pull text files from a web server and save the to my computer. How can I go about doing this? I always get a the error "System.Net.Exception". My code looks like this.

```
using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
{
    webClient.DownloadFile("[URL for source goes here]", 
    @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google"); 
}
```

I am not sure how to get it to download it. When I do try to pull from a URL it just errors every time.

Comment: Welcome to S.O!

Can you please edit your question with more information about what exception has been thrown? Given the code you have provided I would imagine the WebClient is throwing a `WebException`, is that the case?

Comment: Pass a filename as second parameter, and of course read [ASK].

Comment: To further what Michael Hancock said, you'll find it useful to read [ask]. Writing a good question is much more likely to get you good answers! And welcome!

Comment: Also make sure you don't get *access denied*